# Problem when try get $4 with some arguments- YACC -> C

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lex, symbol-table

i was stack when i tried got 2 or more arguments to another condition.
The big idea is to build Symbol Table to identify errors in code, i was build a tree but now we need build the table, but i didnt want to use this tree..
so i try to use with LinkList that i made.
this is my linklist in c:

```
    typedef struct linkList {
        char* data;
        struct linkList* next;
}linkList;
```

sorry that it's not clarity, i will try to explain with exmple.

Here some of my condition:

```
s: Program { };
Program: Proc_Func {$$ = mknode("CODE",$1,NULL); };
Proc_Func: Proc_Func Funct {$$ = mknode("",$1,$2); }
          | Proc_Func Proce {$$ = mknode("",$1,$2); }
          | Funct {$$ =$1;}// mknode("",$1,NULL); }
          | Statement {$$ = mknode("",$1,NULL); }
          | Proce {$$ = mknode("",$1,NULL); }
          |{$$=NULL;};
Funct: FUNC id LBRACKET Param RBRACKET RETURN Type LBRACE Body RBRACE {$$ = mknode("FUNC",mknode("",mknode("",$2,NULL),mknode("ARGS",$4,mknode("RETURN",$7,NULL))),mknode("",$9,NULL)); 
buildLinkList($2,$4,$7,$9);};
Proce: PROC id LBRACKET Param RBRACKET LBRACE Body RBRACE {$$ = mknode("PROC",mknode("",mknode("",$2,NULL),mknode("ARGS",$4,mknode("",$7,NULL))),NULL); };
Param: Param_list {$$ = mknode("",$1,NULL); }
    |{$$ =NULL;};
     
Param_list: Var_id COLON Type {$$ = mknode("",$3,mknode("",$1,mknode(")",NULL,NULL))); }
          | Param_list SEMICOLON Param_list {$$ = mknode("",$1,mknode("",$3,NULL)); };
Var_id: id COMMA Var_id {$$ = $1;}//mknode("",mknode("",$1,NULL),$3); }
      | id {$$ = mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL);};
Type: BOOL {$$ = mknode("BOOLEAN",NULL,NULL); }
    | CHAR {$$ = mknode("CHAR",NULL,NULL); }
    | INT {$$ = mknode("INT",NULL,NULL); }
    | REAL {$$ = mknode("REAL",NULL,NULL); }
    | INT_P {$$ = mknode("INT_P",NULL,NULL); }
    | REAL_P {$$ = mknode("REAL_P",NULL,NULL); }
    | CHAR_P {$$ = mknode("CHAR_P",NULL,NULL); };

Body: Proc_Func Declares Statements {$$= mknode ("BODY",mknode("",$1,NULL),mknode("",$2,mknode("",$3,mknode("",NULL,NULL))));};


Declares: Declares Declare {$$= mknode ("",$1,$2);}
        |{$$=NULL;};
Declare: VAR Var_id COLON Type SEMICOLON {$$= mknode ("VAR",$2,$4);};
Statements: Statements Statement {$$= mknode ("",$1,$2);}
            |{$$=NULL;};
Statement: IF LBRACKET exp RBRACKET ST_Block {$$ = mknode("IF",mknode("(",$3,mknode(")",NULL,NULL)),$5);}
         | IF LBRACKET exp RBRACKET ST_Block ELSE ST_Block {$$=mknode("IF ELSE", mknode("",$3,mknode("",NULL,NULL)),mknode("",$5,mknode("",$7,NULL)));}
         | WHILE LBRACKET exp RBRACKET ST_Block {$$=mknode("WHILE",mknode("(",$3,mknode(")",NULL,NULL)),$5);}
         | ST_Assign SEMICOLON {$$=mknode("",$1,NULL);}
         | exp SEMICOLON {$$=$1;}
         | RETURN exp SEMICOLON {$$=mknode("RETURN",$2,NULL);}
         | NEW_Block {$$=$1;};


ST_Block: Statement {$$=$1;}
        | Declare {$$=$1;}
        | Proce {$$=$1;}
        | Funct {$$=$1;}
        | SEMICOLON {$$=mknode("",NULL,NULL);};
        

NEW_Block: LBRACE Proc_Func Declares Statements RBRACE {$$= mknode ("{",$2,mknode("",$3,mknode("",$4,("}",NULL,NULL))));};
    
ST_Assign: Ll ASSIGN exp {$$= mknode("=",$1,$3);};

Ll: id LSQRBR exp RSQRBR
  | id {$$ = mknode("",$1,NULL); }
  | ;

exp: exp EQUAL exp {$$= mknode ("==",$1,$3);}
   | exp NOTEQ exp {$$= mknode ("!=",$1,$3);}
   | exp BIGGER exp {$$= mknode (">",$1,$3);}
   | exp BIGGEREQ exp {$$= mknode (">=",$1,$3);}
   | exp SMALLER exp {$$= mknode ("<",$1,$3);}
   | exp SMALLEREQ exp {$$= mknode ("<=",$1,$3);}
   | exp AND exp {$$= mknode ("&&",$1,$3);}
   | exp OR exp {$$= mknode ("||",$1,$3);}
   | exp PLUS exp {$$= mknode ("+",$1,$3);}
   | exp MINUS exp {$$= mknode ("-",$1,$3);}
   | exp MULTIPLY exp {$$= mknode ("*",$1,$3);}
   | exp DIV exp {$$= mknode ("/",$1,$3);}
   | NOT exp {$$= mknode ("!",$2,NULL);}
   | BOOLTRUE {$$= mknode ("",mknode("BOOLEAN",$1,NULL),NULL);}
   | BOOLFALSE {$$= mknode ("",mknode("BOOLEAN",$1,NULL),NULL);}
   |id {$$ = mknode("",$1,NULL); }
   |CHAR_LTL {$$= mknode ($1,mknode("CHAR",NULL,NULL),NULL);}
   | NUM {$$ = mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL); };
id: ID {$$ = $1; mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL); };
   //| NULLL;
```

and this is the function to build the link list:

```
    void buildLinkList(char *d1,char *d2,char *d3,char *d4)
{
    linkList *link1 = NULL;
    link1=(linkList*)malloc(sizeof(linkList));
    link1->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(d1)+1);
    strcpy(link1->data,d1);
    linkList* link2= (linkList*)malloc(sizeof(linkList));
    link2->data=(char*)malloc(sizeof(linkList));
    strcpy(link2->data,d2);
    link1->next=link2;
    linkList *link3= (linkList*)malloc(sizeof(linkList));
    link3->data=(char*)malloc(sizeof(linkList));
    strcpy(link3->data,d3);
    link2->next=link3;
    linkList* link4= (linkList*)malloc(sizeof(linkList));
    link4->data=(char*)malloc(sizeof(linkList));
    strcpy(link4->data,d4);
    link3->next=link4;
    //printf("%s",link1->data);
    //printf("%s",link2->data);
```

i try to return the linklist but its not working.. so i try to send all argument to one list.
In condition "Funct" you can see the i called the function buildLinkList, i send $2,$4,$7,$9.

$2- i can "cache" it in my list and sucsses to print it.. but $4 is "param" and it return me some of varible, i cant to push them in my list, when i try to print it i get garbage.
i tried a lot of ways to pass it and another ideas, please help me to crack it, another ideas will be welcomes.

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here (and in the related lines):

```
link1->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(d1)+1);
```

Here, `sizeof(d1)` gives you the size of the *pointer* named `d1`, not the size of the *string* it points at. For strings longer than the pointer size, this will underallocate the space for the string that you then copy over.

To fix this, change `sizeof(d1)` to `strlen(d1)`. Alternatively, look into using `strdup`, which both allocates the space you need and copies over the string contents into that space.

Comment: First of all thank you very much about this answer..!
I tried it and unfortenly its not succesed :( it also give me a garbage..